# How to add matplotlib editing tab to seaborn plots displayed within a canvas?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

When integrating plots within a gui and using the canvas my plots come without the editing tab at the bottom of plots I get when I simply have "plt.show()". How can I add the bottom editing tab in the plot on the left to the plot on the right?

[image]

Edit (once toolbar is implemented but still have some problems):

I use stacked layout to switch in between windows. the two functions fully displayed below are the one's in charge of the window with a drop down menu and plot and updating the plot when a new dropdown option is chosen.

Toolbar is based on https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt_sgskip.html (thanks to ImportanceofBeingErnest)

Simplified Code (can run on its own):
    import sys

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavToolbar
import seaborn as sns

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("Title Window (not sure)")

        self.stacked_layout = QStackedLayout()
        self.stacked_counter = -1

        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.stacked_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.main_window_layout()

    def main_window_layout(self):

        self.bargraph_dropdown_menu_button = QPushButton("Go To Bar Graph DropDown Menu")

        self.main_menu_button_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.main_menu_button_layout.addWidget(self.bargraph_dropdown_menu_button)

        self.main_menu_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_menu_layout.addLayout(self.main_menu_button_layout)

        self.view_main_menu_widget = QWidget()
        self.view_main_menu_widget.setLayout(self.main_menu_layout)

        #connections
        self.bargraph_dropdown_menu_button.clicked.connect(self.dropdown_menu_layout)

        self.stacked_layout.addWidget(self.view_main_menu_widget)
        self.stacked_counter += 1
        self.stacked_layout.setCurrentIndex(self.stacked_counter)


    def dropdown_menu_layout(self):
        self.setMinimumSize(550,350)
        self.setMaximumSize(100000,100000)

        self.homebutton = QPushButton('Back Home')
        self.homebutton.setFixedSize(70,22)

        self.figure = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        def on_resize(event):
            plt.tight_layout()
            self.canvas.draw()
        cid = self.canvas.mpl_connect('resize_event', on_resize)

        self.addToolBar(Qt.BottomToolBarArea, NavToolbar(self.canvas, self))

        sns.set(style="whitegrid")
        plt.cla()
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.set_title('Droops and Power System Parameters to Bus Sensitivity', fontweight=1)
        ax.title.set_position([.5, 1.025])
        ax.set_ylabel("Sensitivity", fontweight=1)
        ax.yaxis.labelpad = 15
        plt.tight_layout()
        sns.despine(bottom=False,top=False,left=False,right=False)
        self.canvas.draw()

        self.button_hbox_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.button_hbox_layout.addWidget(self.homebutton)
        self.button_hbox_layout.addStretch(1)

        self.dropdown_vbox_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.dropdown_vbox_layout.addLayout(self.button_hbox_layout)
        self.dropdown_vbox_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.view_dropdown_menu_widget = QWidget()
        self.view_dropdown_menu_widget.setLayout(self.dropdown_vbox_layout)

        #connections
        self.homebutton.clicked.connect(self.change_to_main_menu_window)

        self.stacked_layout.addWidget(self.view_dropdown_menu_widget)
        self.stacked_counter += 1
        self.stacked_layout.setCurrentIndex(self.stacked_counter)

    def change_to_main_menu_window(self):
        self.setFixedSize(300,75)
        self.stacked_layout.setCurrentIndex(0)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    win.raise_()
    app.exec_()   #sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Main Window:

[image]

Click "Graph DropDow......":

[image]

Click "Back Home" (Supposed to be the same as the Main Window in step one):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to initial question:**

You forgot to add the navigation toolbar to your GUI.
E.g. for PyQt

```
matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg.NavigationToolbar2QT
```

or for Tk

```
matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg.NavigationToolbar2Tk
```

etc. You may refer to [the examples on the matplotlib page](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#embedding-matplotlib-in-graphical-user-interfaces) for all possible GUI backends.

The way how to add the navigation bar depends on the GUI in use, <strike>which is a secret in the question, but you will find out from the respective example.</strike>

**Answer to edited question:**

You are adding the navigation toolbar to the window, not the StackedLayout. So instead of `self.addToolBar(Qt.BottomToolBarArea, NavToolbar(self.canvas, self))` you need to add it to the layout in use,

```
self.dropdown_vbox_layout.addWidget(NavToolbar(self.canvas, self))
```

Comment: I am able to add the navigation toolbar correctly but when navigating between windows in my GUI the added navigation toolbars never leave and clutter the GUI. How do I remove the navigation toolbar once I leave certain windows? Do I need to clear/remove the canvas? If so, how?

Comment: I cannot answer this question without seeing the code that produces this kind of behaviour.

Comment: If it helps I'm using stacked layout to switch in between windows. When I switch to a different window the navigation bar doesn't go away. posted the code above

Comment: Now I'm confused as to what the problem is. The toolbar seems to be set up correctly. What does "navigation bar doesn't go away" mean? Why should it go away?

Comment: I guess it boils down to my first comment here, without a  [mcve], I cannot help.

Comment: There, the code above is complete and verifiable. I tried to make it as minimal as possible as quick as possible (don't have a lot of time, sorry!!!) Thanks for all the help!